# Data encryption between VPN server and the internet

Tags: vpn

I'm sure this is a basic question but I can't seem to find an answer.  I understand that a VPN will encrypt communication between the VPN client and the VPN server.  When the VPN server gives you access to a corporate network, that's fine.  But when used as a personal VPN for something like web browsing, isn't the data between the VPN server and the destination web server totally exposed?  Or am I missing something?

Thanks, Brian

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are correct.  A VPN only encodes data between the client and the VPN endpoint.  The name "Virtual Private Network" suggests that the purpose of a VPN is typically to make your roaming client appear to be part of a remote network.  It is *not* meant to provide secure communication to arbitrary servers on the internet.

However, a VPN still has some utility in this area: if you suspect your ISP of monitoring your traffic, the encryption provided by a VPN allows you to bypass this sort of activity.  So if you're living under a repressive regime, you can read documents proscribed by the government.  Alternatively, if you're a kid at home you can watch your porn without it showing up in any sort of access log.

Comment: Ha, no access logs, gotcha.  But 'man in the middle' attacks are completely possible after the data leaves the VPN server?

Comment: Absolutely.  Using a VPN doesn't change the nature of the problem, it just shifts it to another location.

Comment: Thanks very much.  It seems personal VPN services are leaving out a big part of the story.